# VirtualBox and Skype are bad rendered after sometime

Tags: virtualbox, skype, gui, qt

In Ubuntu 14.04 and 15.10 with A10 (Radeon HD7660) and Intel i5 (Integrated Graphic) respectability, the ui of VirtualBox and Skype are not rendered rightly after sometime.

I researched and discovered that both use QT for their user interface. I do not know if this is  the problem.

I install Gnome Shell and the issue continue.

Here some images [Virtual Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnWxX.png), [Skype Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwZCB.png)

**Updated:**

DragonDisk has the same problem. It uses QT, too.

If you run **sudo service lightdm restart** and all are rendered rightly. But all the applications are closed. This is not practical.

Comment: Same problem here on 14.04, since about 1 week. Suspecting some software update.  Tried to fix it by uninstalling everything related to qt version 5, but had to keep some of it because package "ubuntu-desktop" depens on some.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problems around that time with virtualbox.

I do not have that problem anymore. I notice in my /var/log/dpkg.log.1, that virutalbox-qt was upgraded on Nov 28 to version "4.3.34-dfsg-1+deb8u1ubuntu1.14.04.1". I suppose that upgrade fixed it, while a previous upgrade of either qt or virtualbox broke it.

Comment: In Ubuntu 15.10 the issue was fixed in this last days but I do not know which packages solves the problem. The packages updated I think to solve the problem was libwxgtk(3.0.2), libwxbase (3.0.2) and xserver-xorg-core (1.17.2). Any QT packages.